# Dataset of language families, sub-families and their relations other than Wikidata

Tags: data-request, language

I am interested in language families such as Indoeuropean, Romance languages, Afroasiatic and so on, not individual families (although if the dataset includes languages it doesn't hurt).

Wikidata and Wikipedia have some of this information but it's quite incomplete and several different classifications overlap, which makes it difficult to form the groups.

I am looking to make a clean and more useful version of this:

[image: Familie languages relations (in spanish)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [Glottolog](https://github.com/glottolog/glottolog) data repository is the most comprehensive source of machine-readable data.

Perhaps the easiest way to access the data is [pyglottolog](https://github.com/glottolog/pyglottolog) package.

Comment: They also have direct download options in several formats: https://glottolog.org/meta/downloads. This is amazing, I don't know how I missed this source